# Нужен ли дефис после слова "соло" при перечислении? Пример: "книга соло- и кооперативной игр", "в группе есть соло- и бас-гитаристы"

Tags: дефис

Нужен ли дефис после слова "соло" при перечислении? Пример: "книга соло- и кооперативной игр", "в группе есть соло- и бас-гитаристы"